# What can the differences in slopes tell me?

Tags: regression, statistical-power, differences

I ran regression models on two sets of data, and their plots looked parallel, so I ran a t-test on their slopes and they are indeed different.

I'm wondering what I can quantitatively take away from their difference? I would like to be able to combine the two models into one model by adding a coefficient (the difference) so I can predict one of the regression lines by using the other model and the newly calculated coefficient. They are power regressions. Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: It's not easy to tell you how to interpret it without knowing more about the data. Also, it sounds like the model you are after is a multiple regression with an interaction term.

Comment: You can try programmatically fitting the two data sets with "if set_1 else set_2" logic within the power function, for example "if set_1 then add offset_1 else add offset_2" inside the calculation of the function to be fitted.

Comment: Could you explain exactly how you "ran a t-test"?  This is not a standard setting for a t-test, making it possible the test you ran was invalid or wasn't computed correctly.